# A rough comparison of different derivatives of plere

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, verbs, word-comparison

There seems to be a large number of verbs derived from *plere*, all meaning "to fill" to some extent:
*plere*, *supplere*, *complere*, *implere*, *explere*, *opplere*.
I understand that *replere* means "to refill" and *deplere* "to empty", but the the ones I listed seem to mean pretty much the same thing.
Is there a rule of thumb for the differences between (some of) these verbs?
Are there major differences that I should be aware of?

It doesn't have to be very precise; I am looking for a short overview of differences in context, nuance, or other.
If two or more of these seem to be (almost) synonymous, I have nothing against it.
Even if they are all effectively synonyms, so be it; lack of important differences would be useful knowledge.
For a more fine-grained analysis, it is certainly better to compare less words at a time, but I hope my list of verbs is not unfeasibly long.

For definiteness, let me restrict this question to uses in classical Latin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This, from Dumesnil/Gossett, gives us most of them.

[image: screenshot from a book]

Here is a transliteration of the key content:

> *Implere* is to fill what is quite empty.
>   *Explere*, to complete the filling up, or number. (Also to empty.)
>   *Complere*, to fill up to the top, or with many things.
>   *Replere*, to fill up again.
>   *Opplere*, to fill a surface all over.

It leaves out *supplēre*; from Jentzen's 1853 *Liber Differentiārum Linguæ Latīnæ in Ūsū Juventūtis Literās Studiōsæ* we get

> *Supplemus* id, quod addimus, cum deerat.

which, in conjunction with the word "supplement," I take to comprise the idea of a *needful* or *enhancing* addition.

Comment: Thanks, this is great! I transliterated some of the image so as to make it searchable and accessible.